# Does Spark view engine support anonymous types as viewdata

Tags: spark-view-engine, castle-monorail

I'm setting an anonymous type like this:

```
PropertyBag["model"] = new 
                                {
                                    IsHome = areaId == "Home",
                                    IsGroups = areaId == "Groups",
                                    IsUsers = areaId == "Users",
                                    IsComputers = areaId == "Computers",
                                };
```

And in my view I want to be able to call `model.IsHome` from inside a condition attribute output like this:

```
<a href="/Home" class="dropdown selected?{model.IsHome}">Home</a>
```

But this doesn't seem to work with anonymous types!

I've tried to set my viewdata to object:

```
<viewdata model="object" />
```

Any ideas if this is supported at all?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of doing something similar to what you're trying here: [Late-bound Eval – email templates revisited](http://whereslou.com/2009/01/27/late-bound-eval-email-templates-revisited).  Although it's related to using Spark for email templates, you should be able to do the same in your views.  *It may or may not have an effect on performance though, may want to profile it before and after to make sure.*